# Cython: error while importing a .pxd file

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I am creating a function to solve differential equations. The structure of my package is the following:

```
package
 |- integrate
     |- signature.pxd
     |- rk4.pyx
     |- euler.pyx
```

`signature.pxd` contains the template of the function that has to be defined and given in input to `rk4.pyx` and `euler.pyx`.

The content of `signature.pxd` is:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t FLOAT

cdef class ProblemOde:
    cpdef np.ndarray[FLOAT, ndim=1] evaluate(self, double t, np.ndarray[FLOAT, ndim=1] y):
        return np.ndarray([])
```

My problem is that I am not able to import it in  `rk4.pyx` and `euler.pyx`. I cannot use neither absolute or relative import and if I write:

```
cimport signature
from signature cimport ProblemOde
```

I get the error: `'signature.pxd' not found`

What am I missing? How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** here the `setup.py`

```
# built-in/generic imports
import os
from distutils.core import setup

# third-party imports
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

# list of packages eopack
__module_dir__ = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
packages_eopack = [os.path.join(__module_dir__, 'package', 'integrate', 'rk4.pyx'),
                   os.path.join(__module_dir__, 'package', 'integrate', 'euler.pyx')]

# compiler directives
directives = {'language_level': '3',
              'always_allow_keywords': True}

# compile
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(packages_eopack, compiler_directives=directives, annotate=True),
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
```

Comment: You've built the library out of the cython  source files, have you?

Comment: Since it is a compilation issue, can you share your compilation files/method? (`setup.py`/...)

Comment: @ibarrond please see the EDIT. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the `package` variable come from?

Comment: Sorry, it's a string, since it's an example I copy pasted and modified the relevant parts. Now it's correct.

Comment: I'm guessing `setup.py` is inside `package`. In that case' I believe `from integrate.signature cimport ProblemOde` should do the trick.